# Is Minato a Jinchuuriki?

Tags: naruto

I wonder why Minato is categorized as a Jinchuuriki, considering the following:

1. Madara couldn't be Ten-Tails' host because he's re-animated, and he has to force Obito to revive him
2. Minato is re-animated, just like Madara, and yet he has half the Kurama inside

   1. It's possible that he sealed in him half of Kurama before he died, and yet why on earth Kurama wasn't reincarnated
   2. Or Kurama was sealed in unusual manner that Minato's case defied the norm on sealing tailed beast

Comment: i think the other kurama didn't die when sealed on a dying host which is the 4th Hokage. He just been sealed inside of Shiki Fūjin.

Comment: I also wonder why can't Madara be a jinchuuriki, but the reanimated former jinchuirikis can.

Answer (score 8):

Let's make things straight:

- The former Jinchuuriki, reanimated and reinfused with their respective Bijuu, had the Yin-element rod channel the chakra back from the Gedo Mazo. Once removed, Tobi had to quickly re-seal them inside of the statue, or risk them being freed.

  The seal wasn't a permanent seal, like Naruto's or Killer Bee's, it was a temporary seal used for battling and then removing easily.
- Minato's case is a bit different. Minato used the Shiki Fuujin to seal Kurama's Yin half inside of himself, but then, **he himself** got sealed, along with Kurama's half, into the Death God. That's why the Yin half of Kurama never revived (As it was still sealed), and that's why when Minato got reanimated with Edo Tensei, Kurama was already part of the deal.
- Madara, however, cannot be a Jinchuuriki because when he died, he wasn't. The Edo Tensei revives people at certain states of their lives (usually the time of their deaths, but not always), Madara was not a Jinchuuriki anytime in his life.

Answer (score 0):

Minato (4th hokage) even said it that he sealed half the nine tails into Naruto he sealed the **yang** half of the nine tails in Naruto while sealing the **yin** half in him self...meaning that right now both Naruto and Minato are jinchuriki's of the nine tails.

Comment: Could you add to your answer when this was said, so that future readers will be able to find it?

Answer (score 0):

No, Minato was not a Jinchuuriki. He used reaper death seal to control the excess amount of chakra to contain the tailed beast inside his body.