# Why didn't Minato make himself also the Yin-Kurama jinchuuriki?

Tags: naruto

Since Minato used the Eight Trigrams Seal and the Four Elements Seal to seal Yang Kurama into Naruto, why didn't he use the same set of seals on himself to seal the Yin half? Why Reaper Death Seal? Or into Kushina? Seems like a pointless sacrifice. And waste of Yin Kurama's potential.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is Minato a Jinchuuriki?](http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/5250/is-minato-a-jinchuuriki)

Comment: See the first comment, it explains it properly.

Comment: @Omry Firstly, this question isn't a duplicate of the above mentioned. Secondly, if you know the answer to this question, please do answer it :)

Comment: The question isn't a duplicate (Though quite similar), but the answers there already answer it.

Comment: But this question is asking why Minato didn't seal the whole of Kurama into himself (or Kushina) rather than sealing it into two. The other post is more about his jinchuriki characteristics.

Comment: @Omry I've read the question you've indicated, and it explains how Minato is a jinchuuriki due to Reaper Death Seal. That's absolutely fine. My question is why not the other set of seals for the same result, minus the death. Please consider removing the duplicate tag?

Comment: I agree, the question isn't a duplicate but rather would fall to opinion-base question.

Comment: I disagree. Opinion based would have been something like, "This is the situation. What course of action should he take? Why?" This is just asking for a simple reason WHY he took an action the way he did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Naruto* chapter 503, page 17:

[image]

- Minato decided to seal Kurama into Naruto, primarily because of Jiraiya's words about the "Child of Prophecy", thinking/knowing that Naruto could utilize the Tailes Beast's power to be the saviour of the ninja world.
- Minato tells Kushina that sealing the complete Kyuubi was *not physically possible* and they had to split the beast into the Yin and Yang halves for the sealing. Also, the entire Nine Tails' chakra was too immense to be sealed into an infant.
- Kushina was dying because of the Tailed Beast extraction and therefore she wasn't capable (or wouldn't survive) of becoming a Jinchuriki again.

Due to the aforementioned reasons, Minato decided to seal the Yang half into Naruto (so Naruto could harness the power for good) and the Yin half into himself (as sealing the entire Kurama wasn't possible).

---

**EDIT:**

Minato and Kushina decided that Naruto could become the said child of prophecy with the power of the Kyuubi. Since the entire Kyuubi couldn't be sealed into the infant Naruto, Minato had to use the Reaper Death Seal. So the Kurama's power could be brought down to seal him into Naruto. Also, the [Reaper Death Seal](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Dead_Demon_Consuming_Seal) allowed Minato to choose which half of Kurama should be sealed into Naruto.

So essentially, Minato **did** become the Yin Kurama's jinchuriki and remained that way. But the loss of using the Reaper Death Seal is that, it seals the user's life too. Minato sealed Yang Kurama into Naruto by becoming Yin Kurama's jinchuriki and at the cost of his life.

Comment: Oh no, I can see how my question could be interpreted that way. I'm sorry, I'll edit it just now.

Comment: @Andy356 I've edited the answer accordingly :)

Comment: So... the Eight Trigrams + Four Elements combo couldn't seal the entire Kyuubi, nor could the combo split him into half and seal it? Okay... so probably only the Shinigami was a being powerful enough to cut away Yin Kyuubi. That makes sense... thanks! :)