# Why couldn't Minato store the nine tails in a different way?

Tags: naruto

Why couldn't in reality Minato store half of nine tails in Kushina and the other half in Naruto like in the filler ep 432? That way he and Kushina would have lived..

Or better, why couldn't he store the entire nine tails back in Kushina, prevent her from dying and sparing Naruto the trouble of becoming a jinnchuriki?

Answer (score 1):

A lot of these are speculative, but the main thing is that when they protected Naruto, they took critical injuries and likely were not going to live after that. Minato knew the only thing he could have done to properly seal the 9 tails fast enough was the Reaper death seal. The thing is, That will kill the user, as the reaper takes their soul when its released. Orochimaru survived the reaper, but he summoned it using a mask instead of the jutsu, and it still cost him his body. Minato on the other hand, can't do any such thing, so him surviving this encounter is out of the question.

As for Kushina, besides the fact that she was set to die without Kurama, she still dove in-front of his claw, and it pierced her torso in what is likely a fatal injury. Combining such an injury with her weakened body, and its probably next to impossible to save her life. At that point, Both Minato and Kushina are guaranteed going to die, or at least believe so. Sealing Kurama in either of them will probably still lead to their death.

As for why he only sealed Half of Kurama into Naruto, As per [This](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/23135/20610) answer, He couldn't seal all of Kurama into Naruto. [Minato's](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Minato) Wiki entry notes that it was because Kurama was too powerful to be sealed into a newborn infant.

Edit 1: OP added some concerns in a comment, Responding here:
First, Any time Kurama was resealed in Kushina was filler, and as filler does not need to follow in faith of canon, they could do anything, including contradict the canon content. Second, [Kushina](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Kushina_Uzumaki) even volunteered to have Kurama get resealed inside of her, to drag both of them to death.

> While still weakened, Kushina used her diminished chakra to restrain the Nine-Tails. Despite fearing the trauma would kill her in her current state, Kushina volunteered to have the Nine-Tails sealed back into her body so that it would die with her.

So all in all, Kushina was effectively on deaths door, and had no hope on being saved. She had just spent 10 months pregnant, given birth, had Kurama extracted, and was left in that dying state for up to a few minutes with no medical help. As we found out later on, Naruto survived, but unlike Kushina, he was still healthy, young and strong, and had Sakura, second only to Tsunade in medical prowess, constantly healing him (and help from Hagoromo). So it actually makes sense that he had a solid chance of survival from the resealing. Kushina on the other hand, had several major events drain her power, not including loosing Kurama, so her being strong enough to survive was low at best.

In that respect, He probably could have sealed Kurama back into Kushina, but it most likely would have still left her dead and freed Kurama. A free Kurama would throw the tailed beast balance off, causing war, and Minato did not want to take such a risk when a safe option was available. That safe option, sealing half of kurama into naruto, also had one major benefit in Minatos eye, the fact that he believed Naruto could be the child of prophecy Jiraiya spoke about, and Naruto having access to Kurama's power would greatly help him succeed (that is also brought up in [the answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/23135/20610) I linked earlier).

Comment: Still doesn't explain why Minato didnt seal the other half of the nine tails in Kushina like he did in the filler arc "Jiraya Ninja Scrolls"

Comment: @MartianCactus Took me a while, but I got around to add more details to the answer

Answer (score 0):

I have same opinion here. But if you look more detail, actually in Episode 432 Kushina seal half of the kyuubi on her own and minato did the hakke fuin to seal the other half in Naruto. Which make a lot of sense, do you know that after bijuu extracted from a jinchuriki they can get back to alive if the bijuu reseal? Like what Minato did to Naruto when he lose Yang Kurama. But this happen when Kurama told Gaara that seal the other half would save him. In the case of Kushina, the only thing she know is that she'll died after reseal the kyuubi at her weakest point but in episode 432 Minato convince to seal only half. Minato gamble if she could survive and turn out to be true, she survived. And maybe that's why that kyuubi claw didn't hit them because after Kushina get Kyuubi power she immediately strengthen the Adamantine Chain seal so Minato could do the Hakke Fuin. I wish that was what Minato did. In Tsunade Dream filler Naruto still become Naruto and dream to become just like his dad, villager respect him just because he is hokage son but he gain  real respect after he save the village.

Comment: yes, but we wouldn't have gotten a beautiful anime like Naruto then :P

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure, but I don't think minato was powerful enough to do such a task, and I believe that Minatos plan was to keep Kushina alive but the main reason they both dies was because they both wanted to save Naruto.

Comment: Do you have any sources to validate your claim?

Comment: aahhh well, technically for the 1st part no but why else would minato sacrifice his life if he had another way? I don't remember the EP but they said that Minato wanted kushina to race Naruto with ought him.